# How to transfer data from tabs view fragments to a parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following view, which is a parent fragment holding a viewPager of two child fragments

each fragment is supposed to collect data from users and send it back to the main fragment on Button done click

Button Done click belongs to the Parent fragment

The parent can't be an activity as it is a part of a parent activity itself and must appear to the user in a certain way

Any Suggestions[image] or Ideas please

Answer (score 0):

Declare interface like:

```
interface FragmentInteractor{
    public void sendData(...);
}
```

and then make your parent fragment implement this interface. Once, the user clicks button in child fragment get the parent fragment and cast it to FragmentInteractor

```
(FragmentInteractor)(getParent()).sendData(...);
```

Comment: the issue is there's no buttons in the child fragments to follow this solution, I have to get data on parent button click
which means i need to get data on frag swipe or tap selection, and that wouldn't be in the children view either 
am stuck :D

Comment: Well you could make method in child fragment and call it to send data back. It's a bit tricky to keep references of fragment in view pager. For complex cases like this I would usually use EventBus for communication: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus